# HTML table with grid doesn't behave like div with grid?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, html-table, css-grid

Why does this not work?

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  grid-gap: 3px;
  grid-template-columns: 3fr 1fr;
}
.grid .box {
  display: contents;
}
.grid .item {
  background-color: gold;
}


code {
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 2px 5px;
}
```

```html
<h4>This <code>&lt;table&gt;</code> doesn't behave correctly (Chrome and Firefox support <code>display: contents</code>)</h4>
<table class="grid">
  <tr class="box">
    <td class="item">A</td>
    <td class="item">B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="box">
    <td class="one item">A</td>
    <td class="two item">B</td>
  </tr>
</table>


<h4>This is how it should look like (no <code>&lt;table&gt;</code>)</h4>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="item">A</div>
    <div class="item">B</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="item">A</div>
    <div class="item">B</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because inside the table you have the `tbody` that is generated by the browser. Add `display:contents` in order to pass through it and it will work like expected:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  grid-gap: 3px;
  grid-template-columns: 3fr 1fr;
}
.grid .box {
  display: contents;
}
.grid .item {
  background-color: gold;
}
tbody {
 display:contents
}


code {
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 2px 5px;
}
```

```html
<h4>This <code>&lt;table&gt;</code> doesn't behave correctly (Chrome and Firefox support <code>display: contents</code>)</h4>
<table class="grid">
  <tr class="box">
    <td class="item">A</td>
    <td class="item">B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="box">
    <td class="one item">A</td>
    <td class="two item">B</td>
  </tr>
</table>


<h4>This is how it should look like (no <code>&lt;table&gt;</code>)</h4>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="item">A</div>
    <div class="item">B</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="item">A</div>
    <div class="item">B</div>
  </div>
</div>
```